# using guid datatype in sqlite db

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm using simple poco class with dapper orm. Now I want to move further from testing to data persistance using sqlite db. My poco class has property Id of type Guid.

I've read somewhere that guid type is not native datatype in sqlite and it should be stored as blob or text data type. Is this true? If this is the case and I should store guid value as text inside database how can intercept value in poco class to know if it's text value than parse to guid so it can be used as p`ublic Guid Id { get; set; }`

hope it's not too confusing.

Please ask if you need more info.

update:
I tried with using `TEXT` instead of `Guid` as db datatype but unhandled data exception occur!

```
Error parsing column 0 (Id=54f039c2-03ad-4131-9b76-0cefb753cddf - String)
```

on query statement

```
var books = cnn.Query<Book>("SELECT * FROM Book").AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Have you tried it by chance? Dapper may translate it fine because a `string` of the appropriate format can be cast to a `Guid`.

Comment: I tried with text datatype for Id property and it throws error on var books = cnn.Query<Book>("SELECT * FROM Book").AsEnumerable();

Comment: @neoistheon Error message is included above in Error parsing column line.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that.